# how to load image From Rest Api Into View did Load Method Using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swifty-json, viewdidload, image-loading

I want to load image in View did load method without use of Tableview or collectionView , I have URL of Wordpress Rest Api , I tried to load Image using SwiftyJson , I got Row Values of All Images But Image is not Able to Load  I Found fatal error: Index out of range, please help me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        let url = NSURL(string: "  ")

        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url! as URL)) {(data,response , error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil)
            {

                let swiftyJSON = JSON(data!)
                let entrylevel = swiftyJSON["guid"].arrayValue

                print("\(String(describing: entrylevel))")
                let imagearray = entrylevel[0]["rendered"].string!

                let imageurl = NSURL(string:imagearray)

                if let imagedata = NSData(contentsOf: imageurl! as URL)

                {
                    self.img.image = UIImage(data: imagedata as Data)
                    print("image load")

                }       

            }        

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

and here is my rest api

> [{"id":1509 "date":"2018-02-15T13:33:22",
>   "date_gmt":"2018-02-15T13:33:22" "**guid**": {
>   "**rendered**":"http://thenewschef.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/startup.jpeg"
>   }

Comment: This "let entrylevel = swiftyJSON["guid"].arrayValue" value doesn't have Array but whole response is in Array. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Do you want whole response ["guid"] value into array?

Comment: i want rendered response for image view

Comment: did you checked your whole data is in array or dictionary format?

Comment: the root is not guid it's an array

Comment: still i got fatal error

Comment: @sapna **Use this in Every project for download and load server image by just passing string URL also Cash the image and Display Placeholder image before load the actual image.** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746517/10150796

Answer (score 1):

guid is a dictionary not array try

```
let entrylevel = swiftyJSON[0]["guid"]["rendered"].string
```

also wrap this in

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

   self.img.image = UIImage(data: imagedata as Data)

}
```

and it's better using `Data` instead of `NSData`

//

OR

```
struct Root:Decodable {

  let  guid:InnerItem
}

struct InnerItem:Decodable {

   let rendered:String
}

try {
   let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: data!)

}
catch {

print(error)
}
```